# Composer stuck on `Something's changed, looking at all rules again` while updating laravel to 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I am trying to update my Laravel application. I was at 5.2 and now I am at 5.5. Everything works fine till here.

Now I have changed it to `5.6.*` in my composer file, and no matter how many times I run `composer update`, it gets stuck at

`Something's changed, looking at all rules again (pass #142)`

Doesn't matter how many passes I let it go on for.

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravel/framework": "5.5.*",
        "laravelcollective/html": "5.5.*",
        "jenssegers/agent": "^2.6",
        "doctrine/dbal": "v2.5.5",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~6.0",
        "laravel/cashier": "~6.0",
        "spatie/laravel-backup":"^3.0.0",
        "maatwebsite/excel": "~2.1.0",
        "rap2hpoutre/laravel-log-viewer":"0.8.0",
        "arcanedev/log-viewer": "4.2.*",
        "tymon/jwt-auth": "0.5.*",
        "aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel": "3.1.0",
        "league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "~1.0.0",
        "tecnickcom/tcpdf": "^6.2",
        "ip2location/ip2location-laravel": "^1.0",
        "geoip2/geoip2":"~2",
        "maxmind-db/reader": "~1.0",
        "pusher/pusher-php-server": "~3.0",
        "maknz/slack-laravel": "^1.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "1.0.10"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.0",
        "symfony/css-selector": "3.1.*",
        "symfony/dom-crawler": "3.1.*",
        "filp/whoops": "~2.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "files": [
           "app/helpers.php"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate"
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }
}
```

Initially there was an issue with a third party package `https://github.com/spatie/laravel-backup` which was causing issues but I have tried removing it as well. Still same issue. :(

Comment: I'm not sure but it may be work `composer clear-cache`

Comment: [Related.](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/7665)

Comment: Have you tried using `composer why-not`?

Comment: I did try `why -t`, there is a `why-not` too? But anyway, I did try `why` and I still wasn't able to understand what was going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried removing on dependancy at a time and updating

`"laravel/cashier": "~6.0"`

This one was causing the issue. Changed it to `~7.0` and now it works fine.

Any one else having this issue, just try to remove all dependancies and try installing them one at a time, and most probably you will find the culprit, then you can try updating that one seperately.

Answer (score 0):

For me the culprit was `phpspec/phpspec`, which seems like it is [no longer needed](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/commit/58e4045f6d3a3c44796a5d48fdfdce8b2a40282d#diff-b5d0ee8c97c7abd7e3fa29b9a27d1780) from Laravel `5.2` onwards.

Answer (score 0):

if you install this extension "nesbot/carbon": "^2.17",Just upgrade him

Comment: you should provide proper explanation for why this answer can can correct, your answer seems to be incomplete thus irrelevant

Answer (score 0):

It may need more passes.

I do not know what it is doing, but for me it continued at 980 passes.

Comment: First time I encountered this, just passed 150 passes as I am trying to upgrade Drupal...

Answer (score 0):

Some dependencies are not compatible after we upgrade the version of Laravel. So, we must upgrade the version of some dependencies. This upgrade is clearly outlined in the Laravel documentation.
(https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade)